# how to force resharper to process .cs files, not VisualAssistX?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper, visual-assist-x

I have both Resharper and VisualAssistX installed.
I'm using almost the same shortcuts. For example it's very handy to have one hotkey for "Find Usages". The problem is that When I try to "Find Usages" in .cs file VisualAssistX tries to do that instead of Resharper.

I expect Resharper to do it work in .cs files
And i expect VAx to do it work in .cpp files. How to achieve this effect?

Comment: Feels like there's no way to do that since Visual Studio doesn't provide separate keyboard mapping schemes for different languages, nor does it expose language-specific contexts for keyboard shortcuts other than that for XML text editor.